# How to write an azure function in java to transfer json file from blob storage to cosmos db account? I have tried but I am getting this error

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, serverless

```java
    @FunctionName("TimerTriggerJava2")
    public void run(
        @TimerTrigger(name = "timerInfo", schedule = "*/5 * * * * *") String timerInfo,
        @BlobInput(name = "blob",
        dataType = "binary",connection = "AzureBlobConnection",
        path = "task2blobcontainer/task2blobitem.json") String content,
        @CosmosDBOutput(name = "database", databaseName = "task2db", collectionName = "task2container", 
        connectionStringSetting = "AzureCosmosDBConnection") OutputBinding<String> outputDocument,
        final ExecutionContext context
    ) {
        context.getLogger().info("Java Timer trigger function executed at: " + LocalDateTime.now());
        outputDocument.setValue(content);

    }
}
```

Error:

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.TimerTriggerJava2. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Storage account connection string for 'AzureWebJobsAzureBlobConnection' is invalid.

Comment: Please check whether you are using the correct storage account connection string details or not??

Comment: Where can I find the reference code in java?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error occurs, when you are trying to run locally. You can try this in your `local.settings.json`:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "java",
    "AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType": "files"
  }
}
```